# Count cells bigger than 0, IF empty skip cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a problem writing my formula that should count all selected cells that contain a number bigger than 0 and skip the cells that are completely empty, even when the cell is selected. Excel gives me an error that I selected cells that not contain a number. How can I skip them?

This is my formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(C8:C12;E8:E12;G8:G12;I8:I12;K8:K12;">0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you using the `COUNTIFS()` formula wrong, after each range, there is a criteria. You can't have multiple ranges like that to look through. For more information look [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function) or [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

In your case you are dealing with a non continues range, and one way to deal with that would be [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/countif-with-non-contiguous-range)

So the formula would translate to:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C8:C12","E8:E12","G8:G12","I8:I12","K8:K12"}),">0"))
```

Another formula you could try is:

```
=INDEX(FREQUENCY((C8:C12,E8:E12,G8:G12,I8:I12,K8:K12),0),2)
```

And looking at your data, it seems as though the rest of the columns contain text (not sure, they may be dates). In case they are text values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(C8:K12))*(C8:K12>0))
```

If they are actually dates (assuming from 2018), then you could try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C8:K12)<2018)*(C8:K12>0))
```

I'm assuming this is what you looking for, instead of a VBA based solution due to the tags provided and your formula.

Comment: i want to select this cells: http://prntscr.com/nlutze  and i want that excel would count cells that contains number bigger than 0 and skip empty cells

Comment: @patriot16, The formula provided does exactly that, allthough I think you might be confused with that you can 'select' cells and count. I have added another option for you to try.

Comment: Neat! Actually, there is a stray semicolon in the first formula though.

Comment: Thanks @TomSharpe, lost in translation ;)

Comment: Thank you @JvdV. The 3th formula you wrote works in my case. This one: =SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(C8:K12))*(C8:K12>0))

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it in this particular case by skipping the columns that you don't want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C8:I12>0)*ISEVEN(COLUMN(C8:I12)-COLUMN(C8)))
```

Answer (score 0):

what will be happen if you use the below formula? to you receive an error?

```
=COUNTIF(C8:C12,">0")+COUNTIF(E8:E12,">0")+COUNTIF(G8:G12,">0")+COUNTIF(I8:I12,">0")+COUNTIF(K8:K12,">0")
```

Comment: I tired it but same error. Anyway thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Requirement cannot be done in single formula,

combining 2 or more formula will help fixing the formula.

formula
`=COUNTA(B2:B9,D2:D9)` -- Count all the non blank cell's

`=COUNTIF(B2:B9,"=0")+COUNTIF(D2:D9,"=0")` -- Count all the cells will value as `0`

Subtract both which will give the output you are looking for

Combined formula

`=COUNTA(B2:B9,D2:D9)-(COUNTIF(B2:B9,"=0")+COUNTIF(D2:D9,"=0"))`

[image]